# Show ListView items below the View

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

I would like to create a transparency effect like in the Groove Music App's control bar as shown in the picture. The scroll bar seems to end above the blue bar so it seems that the actual ListView doesn't go below the bar. So how is it possible to make the invisible content of the ListView/ScrollViewer which is hidden below visible again?

Comment: Add both of your ListView and Blue Bar view in a grid. Make the bluebar verticalalignment to bottom. Make its opacity to 0.50. that should take care.

Comment: No, that's the point, I don't want to put the ListView behind, I want to show the Items that were scrolled away to the bottom, otherwise the ListViews ScrollBar would also be behind the blue bar and the last item of the list would not be clickable.

Comment: I just noticed that when the last element is scrolled up, there is a small jump in UI on windows phone. Most definitely this has something to do with some Triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AVK said, to implement the UI as shown in the picture, we can put the ScrollViewer and Blue Bar in a Grid first, then set the Blue Bar's `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom` and give it a `Opacity`. The Blue Bar should have a fixed `Height`.

Then the key point here is setting `Margin` for the content and `VerticalScrollBar` in the `ScrollViewer`. The `VerticalScrollBar` is in the template of `ScrollViewer`. To modify the template of `ScrollViewer`, we can select the "**[ScrollViewer]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Templates**" → "**Edit a Copy...**". Then in the template, we can set `Margin` for `VerticalScrollBar` like:

```xml
 <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,64" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
```

Following is a complete sample demonstrates this:

```xml
<Page x:Class="UWPApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:UWPApp"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle1" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="MouseIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0:0:3" TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator"/>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="TouchIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator"/>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,64" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                <Border x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollViewerScrollBarSeparatorBackground}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,64">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <TextBlock>Test 1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 4</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 5</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 6</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 7</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 8</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 9</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 10</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 11</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Test 12</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Rectangle Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="#FF0085FF" Opacity="0.8" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And it looks like
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your ideas I solved it similar but there ist an important rule in UWP: NEVER put a ListView into a ScrollViewer because it is extremely buggy on touch interection on a mobile device. So what I did is creating a ListView Style Template. The ListView style contains a `ScrollViewer` and an `ItemsPresenter` . In the ScrollViewer I added the property `Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}">` and the Margin is set to the ItemsPresenter

Comment: P.S. It would be nice if you could update your solution, that no others will have the idea to put a ListView into a ScrollViewer because it is really annoying as a W10M user. There are still many Apps in the Store which do that wrong.

Comment: The `ListView` used here is just for convenience and as I didn't limit the height of `ListView`, it won't be scrollable. But you are right, put a `ListView` into a `ScrollViewer` is not a good practice. For the controls that has already have `ScrollViewer` in their template, we can just edit their template. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.